# But to follow (or) but follow (or) but following

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I have a doubt on this sentence.

I hate it when i don't have any other choice **but to follow**...

(or) I hate it when i don't have any other choice **but follow**...

(or) I hate it when i don't have any other choice **but following**...

Which one is correct - to follow (or) follow (or) following ?

Please clarify...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends upon the context of your sentence. All three of them *could be correct*, depending upon the context of your sentence.

However, as general, you can remember it this way,

- **have/had no choice but to do**
- **can/could do nothing but do** ( in most cases )

So, following this, the first sentence of yours will be correct,

> *I hate it when i don't have any other choice but to follow...*

Answer (score 0):

All three can work in the context when you want to say "I am forced to *follow* (the rules)"

> Many men want to be free yet have no choice but to follow what is expected of them.
>
> Many men want to be free yet have no choice but following what is expected of them.
>
> Many men want to be free, but (instead must) follow what is expected of them.

"To follow" and "following" are the infinitive and gerund forms of verb and act as nouns.  The last sentence uses "follow" as the verb, in the form "I want to do A but I do B".

All are somewhat abbreviated sentences, which are grammatically correct and would be understood in context.  However, it can be tricky to write these kind of ellipses until you are very familiar with English, so instead you can say something like:

> I hate it when I have no choice but to follow the rules.

Otherwise your first and third examples are the same, and just fine.